# Using JavaScript fetch() with a php file in a Vue app running on localhost - Relative URL problem

Tags: php, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, fetch

**EDIT:** Question title changed. The original question title was: ***Using a relative URL in a Vue app that works in both production and development***, but this turned out not to be the cause of my problem (see comments below).

I've tried so many things and all I want to do is use a single relative url in a JavaScript `fetch()` method and have it run consistently in both development and production without having to change lots of config files or webpack settings.

In a nutshell I want to `fetch()` a `get-users.php` file which resides in the same directory as the app — nothing fancy or complicated — just a php file that gets some data from a mysql database on the same host.

I can make it work in development, but then it fails in production (`npm run build`), **OR** I can get it working in production but then it fails in development (`npm run serve`). The reason it fails is essentially because **the relative url in production is the root of the `dist` folder, but the relative url in development is the root of the vue project folder** — is that correct?. So in development for example I can use `fetch(public/get-users.php)` which works perfectly, but then in production the `dist` folder doesn't contain a `public` folder so I get a 404 error. I can manually copy and paste the `public` folder to the `dist` folder after each `build`, but this just seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Part of the problem is that I don't fully understand where a file like `get-users.php` should reside. I don't mind if I have to put it in the `public` or `static` folders, but when I do that it fails in production because of the example above. Could someone please explain the role of the `public` folder in a Vue CLI app please? Does it do something under the hood that I don't fully understand? Am I missing something obvious? It seems like such a trivial task to make this work but I'm banging my head against the wall here! Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `vue cli` then all you need is to put your `get-users.php` file inside the `public` folder and access this file without `public` prefix like this:

```js
fetch('get-users.php')
```

This will work as expected for both dev and prod environments because during the build step webpack will copy all static assets from the `public` to the `dist` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately in development I get an error in the console saying `POST http://localhost:8080/get-users.php ... 404 Not Found`. And in production (`/dist`) I get 3 errors, one saying `GET http://localhost/js/app.651b0831.js ... 404 Not Found` (the other two are basically the same but for different bundled files)

Comment: I can fix the production error by adding `publicPath: "./"` to the `vue.config.js` file, but this does nothing to fix the development error — and thus highlighting my problem beautifully :)

Comment: I just created a simple project with `vue cli`, added a `foo.json` file in public folder and was able to fetch in dev and prod modes. Please create a minimal reproducible example of your issue and share it via github or similar service.

Comment: Could you possibly try the `fetch()` with a simple php file please? Something like: `<?php
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
echo json_encode($cars);
?>`

Comment: With PHP it's a little bit harder because it's necessary to install and start a web server with php support. Nowdays I usually access backend API endpoints which are located inside docker containers or deployed on remote servers, so I don't have a web server with php support installed locally :(

Comment: Ok no problem. But thanks to you using a `.json` file in the `fetch()` request I think I may have narrowed the problem down to `.php` files being the issue. The reason I say that is because when I use the exact same code as previously but just change the `fetch()` url to a test `.json` file it works exactly as you described and I get no errors in production or development. This is the behaviour I was expecting but for some reason using a `.php` file breaks something ... ?

Comment: Here's another piece to the puzzle: Using `'POST'` as the `fetch()` method returns a `POST http://localhost:8080/get-users.php ... Not Found` error. But when I use a simple `GET` url such as `fetch('get-users.php?id=123')` I get a `200 OK` response (i.e., the request has succeeded) *BUT* the `.php` file is not parsed correctly and is just returned as raw text in the console **Reponse Payload**

Comment: Well, it seems that you have no php server running locally and your web-server returns `.php` files as a plain text.

Comment: No that's not correct. I have Apache running via XAMPP (localhost) and `.php` files are being parsed correctly in a simple HTML, JavaScript, PHP environment (i.e., without using Vue or the Vue dev server `npm run serve`)

Comment: My guess is that your XAMPP server and vue dev server are running on different ports and that's why `.php` files are not executed as expected when you're trying to access them via vue dev server. Everything should work fine if you fetch your php file with an absolute URL (with port) from a XAMPP web server.

Comment: Ok thank you. You pointed me in the right direction once again and I've since learned — from much Googling — that `.php` files cannot be executed on the *webpack-dev-server* (which is the server that Vue CLI currently uses). My understanding of this is that the *webpack-dev-server* is a **static** file server to serve generated bundles and files. That's fine for HTML/CSS/JS projects but when developing an application that uses `.php` files they cannot be handled by this **static** file server. I'll try to update this question with an answer when I figure out the best approach. Thank you